# Which quotation marks should I use when writing Latin?

Tags: new-latin, punctuation

What is the most common punctuation used by Latin authors from the Renaissance to the present day to indicate a quotation? Ørberg uses “”, while «» is more common in countries where a Romance language is spoken (French, Italy, etc.).

Comment: Anecdotally, I've only ever seen quotations formatted as in English, but I've seen both British and American styles in Latin. I would be curious to know when quotation marks started to be used at all in Latin. This is a good question!

Answer (score 3):

Hic inveniri possunt explicationes illorum "" vel «» in operibus Latine editis usque ad tempora recentiora: https://www.jstor.org/stable/3288661

Comment: As far as I can see, the linked document doesn't at all help answer the question here, which is specifically about quotation marks from the Renaissance onward, and which of the various possible styles to use. The article describes what earlier Latin used in the absence of quotation marks.